# OpenCV fail building for ARM64 target (Android)

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, opencv, c++11

I am trying to create an .so library, containing OpenCV C++ code.
I set up something very basic - using visual studio to build the project, with the "Dynamic shared library (Android)" template.

I downloaded the Android OpenCV SDK from here:
https://opencv.org/releases/

When I build the project for ARM, everything runs fine and I get a lib.so output.
But when building for ARM64, I get the following error:

> E0035 #error directive: This constructor has not been ported to this
> platform
> File: C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\bitset (line 266)

Here is how I set the project properties:

ARM and ARM64:

> Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional include directories = ***<openCV android sdk folder>\sdk\native\jni\include***

ARM:

> Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional library directories = ***<openCV android sdk folder>\sdk\native\libs\armeabi-v7a***

> Properties -> Linker -> Input->  Additional dependencies = ***<openCV android sdk folder>\sdk\native\libs\armeabi-v7a\libopencv_java4.so***

ARM64:

> Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional library directories = ***<openCV android sdk folder>\sdk\native\libs\arm64-v8a***

> Properties -> Linker -> Input->  Additional dependencies = ***<openCV android sdk folder>\sdk\native\libs\arm64-v8a\libopencv_java4.so***

I am able to get the exact same error when building for ARM if I am targeting an android API lower than 21.

Any idea on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, decided to download the OpenCV Android SDK https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/4.4.0 and used NDK instead of compiling the source

Comment: Hey Allan, can you explain the process?